# Cannot add Plugins to my iOS Cordova Application

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a cordova 3.3.0 application that I created using `./create` etc etc now Whe i try to add the device plugin either `phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git`

or


 `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console org.apache.cordova.device` all give me errors, the device plugin is essential to my application. Anyway to add that plugin without using the CLI tools? just git cloning? or a quick fix? I have killed a lot of time on this.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? This way it worked for me: `phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should follow thier new way to add plugins like [Device](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device):

```
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Comment: `[error] project directory could not be found` and I am in the project directory